# Flutter how to save value and user it on other pages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to save a value in a variable or some service so I can use the value in multiple pages. Local storage isn't a good idea so I need to save it in some service provider or something similar can anyone please help how can I create a service and save the value and take it on other pages.

This is my code

```
  Future<http.Response> _trySubmit() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      print(_userEmail.trim());
      print(_userPassword.trim());

      var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();


      map['grant_type'] = 'password';
      map['username'] = _userEmail.trim();
      map['password'] = _userPassword.trim();


      http.Response res = await http.post(
        'http://sublimeapi.netcodesolution.com/token',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: map,
      );
      var data = res.body;
      print(data);
    }
  }
```

The print value look something like this

```
I/flutter ( 5147):{"access_token":"FwYttAQIDDSRpuFFUgzznmMYgMNNfiW4OvQ4","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":86399}
```

I need to save the access_token in some provider or variable to use it on multiple pages Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have limited number of values to save you can use shared preferences. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

However i wouldn't recommend you to use if the number of data you use keep increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Singleton.

```
class Singleton {
  String _myVariable;
  Singleton._privateConstructor();

  static final Singleton _instance = Singleton._privateConstructor();

  factory Singleton() {
    return _instance;
  }
  
  set myVariable(value) => _myVariable = value;
  get myVariable => _myVariable; 
}
```

Instantiate the Singleton at the beginning of the app, in the main() method.

The information of the Singleton will be available only when the app is running, so you should find a way of getting the data to be saved (LocalStorage or from the server) and then initialize the Singleton with that data on every session.

I recommend you to have a look at [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) or a [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) solution.

Answer (score 0):

As your project is getting big you need more variables and functions across entire your app, I would recommend `Provider` https://pub.dev/packages/provider as state management for your app.
just add this to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^4.3.2
```

and run

```
$ flutter pub get
```

and import

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```